# How do I get right-sided bracket to close?

Tags: equations, amsmath, line-breaking

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
F ={} & \frac{(-2)^m} {8}\sum_{K=0}^{}\frac{z^{yK}}{2^{K(y+2)}}\sum_{L=0}^{K}\left(\frac{(-1)^L}{1+ \lfloor  {L/K} \rfloor}  \right)\\
      & \left[ \left(\frac{Ly-m+1}{(y+2)L-m+1}+\frac{(2K-L)y-m+1}{(y+2)(2K-L)-m+1}  \right) \\
      &{-yL/2+m/2-3/2 \choose L}  {-y(2K-L)/2+m/2-3/2 \choose 2K-L}  \\
       &+{-yL/2+m/2 -1 \choose L}  {-y(2K-L)/2+m/2 -1 \choose 2K-L} \right] 
     \end{split}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

The large right bracket does not show up on the right side . It looks like this "\right] " How do I make it show up.

Comment: I think that in latex you cannot use matching delimiters on different lines. If you change your `\left[` and `\right]` into `\Bigl[` and `\Bigr]` you might get what you want.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your code to compile properly, it needs both a `\right.` directive at the end of row 2 (to balance the earlier `\left[` directive) and a `\left.` directive at the start of row 4 (to balance the subsequent `\right]` directive). This is because `\left ... \right` pairs are not allowed to spans rows in a multi-row equation construct.

A separate issue: There's nothing to be gained from encasing an `aligned` environment inside a `split` environment. Use one or the other, *but not both*.

The `amsmath` package provides a macro called `\binom`; please use it in LaTeX documents instead of the Plain-TeX infix syntax `{ ... \choose ...}`.

I would also "open up" the dense-looking four-line expression, by increasing the value of the length parameter `\jot`. This parameter governs the amount the whitespace that's inserted between rows of a multi-line display math construct. In the code below, I increase `\jot` by 3pt relative to its default value (which happens to be 3pt as well).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} %% or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    %% for 'split' environment and '\binom' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\addtolength\jot{3pt} %% default value: 3pt
\begin{split}
F &= \frac{(-2)^m}{8}
  \sum_{K=0}^{}\frac{z^{yK}}{2^{K(y+2)}} %% why no upper limit of summation?
  \sum_{L=0}^{K}
  \left( \frac{(-1)^L}{1+ \lfloor L/K \rfloor} \right) \\
  & \quad \left[
    \left(\frac{Ly-m+1}{(y+2)L-m+1}+
          \frac{(2K-L)y-m+1}{(y+2)(2K-L)-m+1}
    \right)
    \right. \\ %% \right. balances \left[
  & \qquad
      \binom{-yL/2+m/2-3/2}{L}
      \binom{-y(2K-L)/2+m/2-3/2}{2K-L}  \\
  & \qquad \left. %% \left. balances \right]
    {}+ \binom{-yL/2+m/2 -1}{L}
        \binom{-y(2K-L)/2+m/2 -1}{2K-L}
    \right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `\left` in one line and the matching one in another. The required size is `\bigg`, so it's easier to use `\biggl` and `\biggr`.

In order to make things clearer, it's better to use symbols for multiplication and to stagger the last two lines so it becomes clearer that they pertain to the square brackets.

You're missing an upper bound, where I put `???`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F={}
& \frac{(-2)^m}{8} \sum_{K=0}^{???}
  \frac{z^{yK}}{2^{K(y+2)}}\sum_{L=0}^{K}
  \frac{(-1)^L}{1+ \lfloor L/K \rfloor}
\\
& \cdot \biggl[ \biggl(\frac{Ly-m+1}{(y+2)L-m+1}+\frac{(2K-L)y-m+1}{(y+2)(2K-L)-m+1}\biggr)
\\
& \quad \cdot \binom{-yL/2+m/2-3/2}{L} \binom{-y(2K-L)/2+m/2-3/2}{2K-L}
\\
& \quad + \binom{-yL/2+m/2 -1}{L} \binom{-y(2K-L)/2+m/2 -1}{2K-L} \biggr] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note `\binom` rather than `\choose` (which works but issues a warning and should be avoided in LaTeX). I removed a pair of useless braces and the useless `aligned`.

[image]

In this particular case I find `F={}&` better than `F&=`, because you can so avoid guessing the width of `=` for the alignment. An alternative would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F&=
  \frac{(-2)^m}{8} \sum_{K=0}^{???}
  \frac{z^{yK}}{2^{K(y+2)}}\sum_{L=0}^{K}
  \frac{(-1)^L}{1+ \lfloor L/K \rfloor}
\\
&\quad \cdot \biggl[ \biggl(\frac{Ly-m+1}{(y+2)L-m+1}+\frac{(2K-L)y-m+1}{(y+2)(2K-L)-m+1}\biggr)
\\
& \qquad \cdot \binom{-yL/2+m/2-3/2}{L} \binom{-y(2K-L)/2+m/2-3/2}{2K-L}
\\
& \qquad + \binom{-yL/2+m/2 -1}{L} \binom{-y(2K-L)/2+m/2 -1}{2K-L} \biggr] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Take your pick.

Comment: +1 and congratulations on the 1m points milestone!